# Liquibase rollback not working in Sprintboot 2.0

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

How does liquibase rollback works with springboot application? Would appreciate your inputs.

Here is what i tried - I am creating TableA and TableB in Oracle within a changeset.

TableB already exists in the database, I expect liquibase to rollback TableA as changeset fails while creating TableB but liquibase creating TableA and failing with the below error and never executes rollback block, which is strange:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Liquibase Configuration:

```
<changeSet id="rollback" author="test_user">
<validCheckSum>any</validCheckSum>

    <sqlFile path="db/changelog/changes/DML/ddl.sql"/>
    <sqlFile path="db/changelog/changes/DML/ddl.sql"/>

    <rollback> drop table TABLEA;</rollback>
    <rollback> drop table TABLEB;</rollback>
</changeSet>
```

ddl.sql

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA
    (
        TEST_COL       VARCHAR2(100)
    );

    dml.sql 

    CREATE TABLE TABLEB
    (
        TEST_COL       VARCHAR2(100)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a wrong perception of what the `rollback` is for. It's **not** for "reverting one big transaction within a whole changeSet". It's for reinstating some past schema state.

According to Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm)

> Oracle Database issues an implicit COMMIT before and after any data
>   definition language (DDL) statement.

So after every `create table` statement execution, Oracle commits the transaction.

If the error happens during the execution of a changeSet, liquibase can rollback only a failed transaction, which it does.

Check out this [thread](https://forum.liquibase.org/topic/automatic-rollback-support-how-is-this-invoked-for-create-table-failure)

> Liquibase does not automatically roll back changes made during a deploy if there was an error. Rather, it can roll a database back to a previous schema state when you ask it to. In some cases, it can do that without you explicitly saying how to do the rollback.
>
> It would be better to think of the rollback command in Liquibase as
>   'undo deploys' rather than a transactional rollback.

Also, check out this [liquibase-rollback](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-rollback) article on how to use rollbacks.